# Visual Studio Apache cordova tool returns error command failed with exit code 8 when build

Tags: android, git, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

My app was building normally until i have problem with admob (https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro) plugin Which i remove and re-install not knowing that version of the plugin have been updated with newer version in Git. Since then my app have refuse to build and always return with \build.bat command failed with exit code 8 when building with device or emulator but always work fine in ripple,even if i remove the plugin I will still get the same error. if i create a new project try to build with the device or emulator everything still work. But this particular project have refuse to build or create apk. The error below is what i always get. Do anyone have an idea what might have been causing this problem.

```
new_storemobile\NPK.Mobile\bld\Debug\platforms\android\co      rdova\node_modules\q\q.js:126 (TaskId:36)
1>                      throw e; (TaskId:36)
1>                            ^ (TaskId:36)
1>  Error code 1 fonr command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,C:Desktop\new_storemobile\NPK.Mobile\bld\Debug\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen (TaskId:36)
 1>  Command finished with error code 8:   C:new_storemobile\NPK.Mobile\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug,--ant, (TaskId:36)
 1>MDAVSCLI : error : Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
1>Done executing task "MdaVsCli" -- FAILED. (TaskId:36)
1>Done building target "BuildMDA" in project "NPK.Mobile.jsproj" -- FAILED.:  ( TargetId:26)
  1>
1>Project Performance Summary:
 1>    269683 ms  C:\new_storemobile\NPK.Mobile\NPK.Mobile.jsproj   1 calls
 1>              269683 ms  rebuild                                    1 calls
 1>
 1>Target Performance Summary:
 1>        0 ms  BeforeBuild                                1 calls
 1>        0 ms  CleanPublishFolder                         1 calls
1>        0 ms  CleanReferencedProjects                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  CoreBuild                                  1 calls
1>        0 ms  _SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence     1 calls
1>        0 ms  CompileTypeScript                          2 calls
 1>        0 ms  _CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform   1 calls
 1>        0 ms  Clean                                      1 calls
 1>        0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
 1>        0 ms  TypeScriptClean                            1 calls
 1>        0 ms  TrackJsChanges                             1 calls
 1>        0 ms  _BeforeBeforeRebuild                       1 calls
 1>        0 ms  BuildOnlySettings                          1 calls
 1>        0 ms  CoreClean                                  1 calls
 1>        0 ms  BeforeRebuild                              1 calls
 1>        0 ms  AfterClean                                 1 calls
 1>        0 ms  CleanCordovaDeploy                         1 calls
 1>        0 ms  MDACleanAfterInstall                       1 calls
 1>        0 ms  AfterBuild                                 1 calls
 1>      125 ms  PreComputeCompileTypeScript                1 calls
 1>     2485 ms  BeforeClean                                1 calls
 1>    122466 ms  BuildMDA                                   1 calls
 1>    144607 ms  EnsureNodeJsRequirementsAreAtCorrectVersion   1 calls
 1>    144607 ms  InstallMDATargets                          1 calls
 1>
 1>Task Performance Summary:
 1>        0 ms  Message                                    3 calls
 1>        0 ms  Delete                                     4 calls
  1>        0 ms  CreateItem                                 1 calls
 1>        0 ms  MakeDir                                    1 calls
1>        0 ms  ReadLinesFromFile                          1 calls
 1>        0 ms  WriteLinesToFile                           1 calls
 1>        0 ms  AssignProjectConfiguration                 1 calls
 1>        0 ms  FindUnderPath                              2 calls
 1>        0 ms  RemoveDuplicates                           1 calls
 1>        0 ms  MdaTrackJsChanges                          1 calls
 1>        0 ms  AssignTargetPath                           1 calls
  1>       16 ms  CreateBuildInfoMetadata                    1 calls
  1>      109 ms  VsTsc                                      1 calls
   1>     2485 ms  RemoveDir                                 10 calls
  1>    122451 ms  MdaVsCli                                   1 calls
  1>    144607 ms  CallTarget                                 4 calls
   1>    144607 ms  RunMdaTargetsInstall                       1 calls
   1>
   1>Build FAILED.
  1>
  1>Time Elapsed 00:04:29.68
 ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: did you installed the extras mentioned in the **Notice** section in https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro#how-to-use ? The Visual Studio 2015 will not help you to install that, so I think it's worth to check.

Comment: @AlanYao, I have uninstall Admob plugin completely but still having the same error

Comment: OK. I need to analysis the verbose build log. In visual studio, go to menu Tools->Options-> Project and Solutions -> Select "Diagnostics" in MSBuild project build output verbosity.  Build the project again and share the entire log to me(here or online file service with link).

Comment: @AlanYao Thank i have move my code to another Older version and everything is now working well.